# Python Sockets - Using Coordinates getPos

Tags: python, sockets

Basically trying to use client to send coordinates of a character on the screen and then broadcast that to the other client so it draws the character on the screen. 
Yet i'm getting the following errors:

1. Client Side: `s.send((y))`
2. Server Side: `ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10`

Client Code that i get error on:

```
def updatecoords(task):
    s.send(name)

    print 'Name sent...'


def updatepos(task):
    y = format(Cat.getPos())
    s.send((y))
    print 'Position sent'


    return Task.cont
def readServer(task):
    try:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print data
    except:
        print 'no data received'
    return Task.cont
```

Server Code that i get error on:

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((HOST,PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)
conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
print('Someone connected.He :%s%addr')
while True:

    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    data = pickle.loads(data) # Or json.loads(data)
    print "Got id: {message_id}, data: {message}".format(**data)
```

Comment: You haven't posted the traceback but am I right if I say that the error is in line `data = pickle.loads(data) # Or json.loads(data)`?

Comment: Please post the traceback and the complete code for both client and server.

Comment: Are you using some sort of global socket objects in the client? Also you seem to be trusting that everytime you read from the socket, you will get all data. That's rarely true, and you should *always* make sure you get *all* of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to unpickle the received data:

```
data = pickle.loads(data)
```

But you are not pickling the data before sending it:

```
y = format(Cat.getPos())
s.send((y))
```

Also you have to decide which serialization protocol you wan't to use because `pickle` and `json` are not compatible and this comment:

```
# Or json.loads(data)
```

suggests that you think both `pickle` and `json` should be able to deserialize received data.

So instead of using `format` you should make your client function similar to this:

```
def updatepos(task):
    y = pickle.dumps(Cat.getPos())
    s.sendall(y)
    print 'Position sent'
```

But still this server code:

```
data = pickle.loads(data)
print "Got id: {message_id}, data: {message}".format(**data)
```

will work only under two conditions:
- class `Cat` is imported on server side, otherwise pickle.loads will throw `UnpicklingError` since pickle protocol preserves class name and unpickling restores the object of class `Cat` but it can't be done if definition of this class is unavailable
- `Cat.getPos()` returns a `dict` (or dict-like object) with keys `message_id` and `message`, otherwise `format(**data)` will throw `ValueError` if data can't be used as dict or `KeyError` if one of the mentioned keys is missing in dict

You should also notice that I've replaced `s.send((y))` with `s.sendall(y)` since the first one doesn't guarantee that all data will be sent as documentation says https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send
I've also dropped additional brackets around `y` - this doesn't change anything but they are not needed.

As you have posted only part of your code, I was only able to resolve issues present in the posted code sample.

Comment: Thanks alot. That got rid of that error. However i get another error thats different but doesn't show me where in the code. 1) Server side error = No Module named libpanda. 2) Client Side Error: return getattr(self._sock name)(*args). Am on mobile atm but will post code when i get to my computer

Comment: Since these are different issues preferably you should post it as another question. Feel free to post a link for the new question in the comment here - I'll take a look then and try to help you.

Comment: Yep its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391929/python-sockets-return-getattrself-sock-nameargs